# How to adjust text size dynamically - Prevent text overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a list with some tiles containing texts, but they can't be big enough that it will break the layout. So I take only a substring from the text and add '...' to them to indicate there's more text hidden by the layout.
Problem is, some texts are in caps lock and that makes the text have different sizes.
Here is the sample code for the tile:

```dart
class _MessageTileState extends State<MessageTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colorGrey = Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor;
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        messageIcon(widget.message),
        SizedBox(width: 16.0),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.message.author.length > 38 ? widget.message.author.substring(0, 35) + '...' : widget.message.author,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: screenSize.width * 0.033,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                height: 1.6,
                color: widget.message.read ? colorGrey : null,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              widget.message.title.length > 38 ? widget.message.title.substring(0, 35) + '...' : widget.message.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: screenSize.width * 0.033,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                height: 1.6,
                color: widget.message.read ? colorGrey : null,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              widget.message.message.length > 38 ? widget.message.message.substring(0, 35).replaceAll('\n\n', ' ') + '...' : widget.message.message.replaceAll('\n\n', ' '),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: screenSize.width * 0.033,
                height: 1.6,
                color: widget.message.read ? colorGrey : null,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm a').format(widget.message.date),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: screenSize.width * 0.033,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: colorGrey,
                height: 1.6,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

And here is a image showing the problem:

[image]

I want the text to occupy the same amount of space, regardless of being in uppercase or lowercase. (Making a simple check for upper or lower case doesn't work cause "there ARE TEXTS like THIS on those TILES" - different amount of lowercase and uppercase letters).

PS: Monospace font didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not apply substring or anything.

Please try a `Text()` property called `overflow` and `maxLines`

```
Text(
   "your long very long text",
   maxLines: 1,
   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
)
```

**UPDATE:**

You should reestructure some things also.

Inside your Row, try using only 2 Widgets. One `Container` and one `Expanded`

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
     Container(
        child: messageIcon(widget.message)
     ),
     Expanded(
        child: Column(
         // ... all your column code
        )
     ),
  ],
),
```

[Documentation for: TextOverflow enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TextOverflow-class.html)

Comment: All tiles are overflowing now and it's creating numerous lines, I want just one line with '...' :
A RenderFlex overflowed by 52 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Row

Comment: also add the maxLines: 1

Comment: that solved the number of lines, but it's still giving overflow error for all tiles

Comment: I wrapped the Text widget with a container and passed a width size based on screen width. This is giving me better results, although it's not perfect. Thanks for the help.
Result: https://i.imgur.com/P51tP3e.png

Comment: I updated my answer. Check. Try to avoid using the "based on screen width". In this case you can get the desired results without it.